# How to display only specific Error types in debug.log? No notices, warnings, etc

Tags: php, debug, notices, wp-debug

I can't find the right way to make it work.
I tried many things, like putting this in wp-config.php

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false);
define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', 'wp-content/themes/mytheme/mylog.log' ); // yeah, customized it a bit. It logs everything
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ERROR );
```

also tried to set it in the php.ini on various websites i manage.
Not on managed hosting. Or at least not on the well known international ones.
Can it be server side or syntax error, or not even possible what i want?

Thanks!

Comment: maybe try including ini_set after wp_debug. Not sure whether this will work or not

Comment: @RaashidDin Can you show with code, exactly how you mean it, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short: [this is the most detailed documentation on the topic](https://wordpress.org/support/article/editing-wp-config-php/) (most likely..)
 The only source you need.

Oh, and here is an amazing [Php Error Level calculator](https://maximivanov.github.io/php-error-reporting-calculator/) to set up the php error mask binary code fast (if needed)

Based on this, i made my custom error reporting:
In `functions.php`

```
function error_report_log_customize(){
    // error_reporting(E_ALL);
    // error_reporting(E_NOTICE);
    // error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_NOTICE);
    error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_WARNING);

    // helpful tool https://maximivanov.github.io/php-error-reporting-calculator/
}
add_action('init','error_report_log_customize');
```

In `wp-config.php`

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', 'wp-content/themes/my-theme/my-logfile.log');
define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false);
```

Only thing I'm not 100% sure about which hook is the best for this. `init` seems working so far, but anyone with better insight, pls comment.